# Disable Rematch in Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I use Google Play Games Services and everythink working fine (leaderboards, random opponent etc etc)

But when a player call finishMatch(), the status of match.canRematch() is always "true", beyond the result.
If the player has won the battle may not be able to ask for a rematch!
I use this code to send the result:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(mGoogleApiClient,
            mMatch.getMatchId(), mMatch.getData(), myscore, creatorscore).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(
                        TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                } 
            });
```

I would like to disable the possibility of revenge. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  This *IS* an answer.

It is not possible from the API to disallow rematch.

However, I just discovered a workaround that achieves the same effect.

1. detect whether a match is a rematch by calling getMatchNumber() and getPreviousMatchData().  Cancel/Dismiss the match if the former isn't 1 or the latter isn't null.  It ensures a rematch user input will have the same effect as a dismissal.
2. when a match is completed completely (cancelled, expired, or MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETE && MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE), dismiss it right away.  It minimizes the chance that the user will even see the "Match complete, rematch" UI.  This check can also be checked periodically for matches in the inbox.

Comment: Yeah... the problem of avoiding the rematch is really with the UI. But @Michael Lam's 2nd point is what I use to. Just excecute dismiss(). It will knock it out of the UI, hence know chance of asking for a rematch!